# Polymer 1.x: Databinding Arrays

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

#### Objective

I want to databind the `selected` property [in this element](http://jsbin.com/yosajuwime/1/edit?html,console,output) to the DOM (at `<div>[[selected]]</div>`).

After selecting a state (like "Texas"), I expect the state's name to appear in the upper left next to the pre-selected states of "Colorado,South Dakota" (inside the `<div>[[selected]]</div>` tag). But instead, it does not.

#### Question

What's going on here? How can I successfully databind the DOM to the `selected` property? And have the DOM update automatically with each new state that is selected and de-selected.

#### Reproduce the Problem

Follow these steps:

1. [Open this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yosajuwime/1/edit?html,console,output).
2. Observe the pre-selected states are Colorado and South Dakota.
3. Notice Colarado and South Dakota are listed in the upper left.
4. Click Texas.
5. Observe the state of Texas is selected in the chart.
6. ❌ Notice the state of Texas ***is not included*** in the list of selected states in the upper left. i.e., `<div>[[selected]]</div>`
7. Click the button labeled "Show Values" and observe in the console that "Texas" is included in the `selected` array.

#### Attempted solution using .slice() crashes

[This SO answer explains why mutated arrays are not directly observable by the Polymer object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35365321/1640892).

@ScottMiles writes:

> ...you are doing work where Polymer cannot see it (i.e. the array manipulations), and then asking `set` to figure out what happened. However, when you call `this.set('selected', selected);`, Polymer sees that the identity of `selected` hasn't changed (that is, it's the same Array object as before) and it simply stops processing.

So I attempted to solve the problem by creating a new array using the `.slice()` method on the original array as follows.

http://jsbin.com/yosajuwime/1/edit?html,console,output

```
// Sort new 'selected' array
_selectedChanged: function(selectedInfo) {
  var selected = this.selected.slice();
  selected.sort();
  //this.set('selected', selected); // Uncommenting this line crashes call stack
},
```

This seems to solve the observability problem but creates a side effect issue and crashes the call stack.

#### Source

http://jsbin.com/yosajuwime/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import"> </head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-element"> <template>
      <style>
        google-chart {
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <button on-tap="_show">Show Values</button>
    <button on-tap="clearAll">Clear All</button>
    <button on-tap="selectAll">Select All</button>
    <div>[[selected]]</div>
    <google-chart id="geochart"
                  type="geo"
                  options="[[options]]"
                  data="[[data]]"
                  on-google-chart-select="_onGoogleChartSelect">
    </google-chart>
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {

        // google-chart monkey patch
        var gcp = Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('google-chart'));
        gcp.drawChart = function() {
          if (this._canDraw) {
            if (!this.options) {
              this.options = {};
            }
            if (!this._chartObject) {
              var chartClass = this._chartTypes[this.type];
              if (chartClass) {
                this._chartObject = new chartClass(this.$.chartdiv);
                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(this._chartObject,
                    'ready', function() {
                        this.fire('google-chart-render');
                    }.bind(this));

                google.visualization.events.addListener(this._chartObject,
                    'select', function() {
                        this.selection = this._chartObject.getSelection();
                        this.fire('google-chart-select', { selection: this.selection });
                    }.bind(this));
                if (this._chartObject.setSelection){
                  this._chartObject.setSelection(this.selection);
                }
              }
            }
            if (this._chartObject) {
              this._chartObject.draw(this._dataTable, this.options);
            } else {
              this.$.chartdiv.innerHTML = 'Undefined chart type';
            }
          }
        };

        Polymer({
          is: 'x-element',
          /** /
           * Fired when user selects chart item.
           *
           * @event us-map-select
           * @param {object} detail Alpabetized array of selected state names.
          /**/
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming', ].sort();
              },
            },
            color: {
              type: String,
              value: 'blue',
            },
            options: {
              type: Object,
              computed: '_computeOptions(color)',
            },
            selected: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [];
              }
            },
            data: {
              type: Array,
              computed: '_computeData(items, selected.length)'
            },
          },
          observers: [
            '_selectedChanged(selected.length)',
          ],
          _computeOptions: function() {
            return {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              legend: 'none',
              defaultColor: 'white',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#E0E0E0', this.color],
                minValue: 0,  
                maxValue: 1,
              }
            }
          },    
          // On select event, compute 'selected'
          _onGoogleChartSelect: function(e) {
            var string = e.path[0].textContent.split('Select')[0].trim(), // e.g. 'Ohio'
                selected = this.selected, // Array of selected items
                index = selected.indexOf(string);
            // If 'string' is not in 'selected' array, add it; else delete it
            if (index === -1) {
              this.push('selected', string);
            } else {
              this.splice('selected', index, 1);
            }
          },
          // Sort new 'selected' array
          _selectedChanged: function(selectedInfo) {
            var selected = this.selected.slice();
            selected.sort();
            //this.set('selected', selected); // Uncommenting this line crashes call stack
          },
          // After 'items' populates or 'selected' changes, compute 'data'
          _computeData: function(items, selectedInfo) {
            var data = [],
                selected = this.selected,
                i = items.length;
            while (i--) {
              data.unshift([items[i], selected.indexOf(items[i]) > -1 ? 1 : 0]);
            }
            data.unshift(['State', 'Select']);
            return data;
          },
          clearAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', []);
          },
          selectAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', this.items);
          },
          _show: function() {
            //console.log('items', this.items);
            console.log('selected', this.selected);
            //console.log('data', this.data);
          },
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-element color="red" selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'></x-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `set` crashes the call stack because you are effectively saying: "when the selected array changes, change the selected array", which is an infinite loop. Fwiw, your solution to bind to compute a sorted, concatenated string is a good one, since your output is relatively simple.

Comment: [I wrote this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBsxZLkfg5fxFEXW06H9?p=preview) to see if there were any problems having external elements observe changes to array properties through a databinding without having to take any additional steps. Apparently, everything works fine when the observer is an external element ... http://plnkr.co/edit/NBsxZLkfg5fxFEXW06H9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind array you have to use the dom-repeat.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[selected]]">[[item]] </template>
```

http://jsbin.com/soxedeqemo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: A key bit to note here is that `dom-repeat` has built in sorting facility that should be used instead of sorting the actual data array. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of `dom-repeat` doesn't support proper use of comma delimiters. So I used a computed property string instead.

http://jsbin.com/ruduwavako/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<div>[[selectedString]]</div>
...
selectedString: {
  type: String,
  computed: '_computeSelectedString(selected.length)',
},
...
_computeSelectedString: function(selectedInfo) {
  return this.selected.sort().join(', ');
},
```

Comment: why?
You can format the dom-repeat as you want.
But if it solve the problem is ok..

Comment: I think @mowzer is saying that if you repeat `<span>{{name}},</span>` you end up with a trailing comma. It's true you can fix this with extra logic, but for this kind of ultra simple output, computing the string is an efficient solution.

Comment: [I wrote this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBsxZLkfg5fxFEXW06H9?p=preview) to see if there were any problems having external elements observe changes to array properties through a databinding without having to take any additional steps. Apparently, everything works fine when the observer is an external element ... http://plnkr.co/edit/NBsxZLkfg5fxFEXW06H9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Databinding arrays can be tricky.

[So here is a complete implementation example](http://jsbin.com/xonanucela/edit?html,console,output).

http://jsbin.com/xonanucela/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<x-element></x-element>

<dom-module id="x-element">
<template>

  <br><br>
  <paper-button on-tap="_addNew">Click To Add</paper-button>
  <p>
    <strong>Items</strong>:
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <span>[[item]] </span>
    </template>
  </p>

</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-element',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return ['foo'];
        }
      }
    },
    _addNew: function() {
      var a = this.items; // Clones array
      a.push('bar'); // Updates "value"
      console.log('a', a);
      this.set('items', a.slice()); // Updates "identity"
      console.log('items', this.items);
    },

  });
</script>
</dom-module>
</body>
```